# Set a Thumbnail to a mp3 file

Tags: mp3

Is there a way to manually set/change the Thumbnail of an .mp3 file?

Is there any section in the mp3 file where the tags and the thumbnail are stored, or maybe some freeware wich allows me to do so?

Iam Using windows 7 professional x64.

Comment: Impossible to answer if you don't tell us which OS you're using.

Comment: How many minutes you spend on this topic ? I found this on google in 5 seconds... http://techstrick.blogspot.de/2012/01/how-to-add-image-or-picture-to-mp3.html

Answer (score 0):

USe applications like n7 player which automatically generate thumbnail or you can download.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.n7mobile.nplayer&hl=en